# Ringtones and alarms changes randomly

Tags: settings, ringtone

3 weeks ago my HTC EVO 3d (rooted, S-OFF and with LEEDroid latest ROM) started to randomly change ringtones and alarm tones (mainly at reboot, but occasionally during normal use).

If I restore the right tones settings then the right tones are played, until I reboot the phone. When the phone restarts (and sometimes also without rebooting) tones changes again.

New tones are random, but the pool is limited to a very small subset of the tones I have availables (the tones I use more often) Some of them are on internal memory and some of them are on SD.

Moreover, another problem appeared at once: the alert tone for received mail in the mail app (NOT gmail) should be the one set in the "message" setting (in Mail there's no place to set a separate tone) but on my phone it is not... it's another tone that I never set anywhere.

Already tried to fix permissions, check for SD errors, but no result.

There's something I can check to see what is failing in the system? I can use adb and all the development tools if needed.